# Automatic Listener Rule Priority in AWS ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-application-load-balancer

This is in continuation to -
[Automatically set ListenerRule Priority in CloudFormation template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50003378/automatically-set-listenerrule-priority-in-cloudformation-template)

I tried the solution, mentioned in the link above, and have been using it successfully. However, there's a challenge now. This solution worked great on Python 3.6. But it's no longer supported. Tried running this solution on higher versions - 3.7, 3.8 & 3.9 but no luck. Can someone please help with a compatible code that can run on Python 3.8 or 3.9.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get my old code working using Lambda Layers:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-concepts.html#gettingstarted-concepts-layer

In my case specifically I had to use the following layer:

```html
Runtime: python3.9
Layers:
 - 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:336392948345:layer:AWSSDKPandas-Python39:7'
```